# Why I put the variable T but I can't get two curve in the graph?

Tags: matlab

the variable `nowT` is a constant but I don't know how to fix it, it need to be a matrix

My code is:

```
lambda1=1.064; % unit:um
lambda2=0.532; % unit:um
T=0:500;
nowT=(4.9130+(0.1173+T.*T.*1.65e-8)/(lambda1.*lambda1-(0.212+T.*T.*2.7e-8).^2)-lambda1.*lambda1.*2.78e-2);
ne2wT=(4.5567+T.*T.*2.605E-7+(0.097+T.*T.*2.7E-8)/(lambda2.*lambda2-(0.201+T.*T.*5.4e-8).^2)-2.24E-2.*lambda2.*lambda2);
figure('name','temperature phase matching chart','NumberTitle','off')
plot(T,nowT,T,ne2wT);
```

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want element-wise division in `nowT`, like this:

```
nowT=(4.9130+(0.1173+T.*T.*1.65e-8)./ ...
(lambda1.*lambda1-(0.212+T.*T.*2.7e-8).^2)-lambda1.*lambda1.*2.78e-2);
```

The change is simply `...1.65e-8)./(lambda1...` instead of `...1.65e-8)/(lambda1...`

That code gives the following figure in [Octave Online](https://octave-online.net/).

[image]